# Can't Connect to MySQL Database using WP CLI and MAMP on a macOS Catalina, using Oh My Zsh

Tags: wp-cli, localhost

I'm running macOS Catalina and am trying to use WP CLI with MAMP, with iTerm2 and Oh My Zsh as my command line.

However in my localhost directory when I enter `wp` in the command line, and then press `q` to exit, I get the following errors:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SERVER_NAME in phar:///usr/local/Cellar/wp-cli/2.4.0/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1197) : eval()'d code on line 5  
Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_NAME in phar:///usr/local/Cellar/wp-cli/2.4.0/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1197) : eval()'d code on line 5
PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Users/mattpjennings/Desktop/projects/mj/build/mj.net/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1626
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /Users/mattpjennings/Desktop/projects/mj/build/mj.net/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1626
```

Then when I enter `wp plugin list` I also get the error below:

```
Error: Error establishing a database connection.
```

When I enter `wp --info` I get:

```
PHP binary: /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.6/bin/php
php.ini used:   /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini
```

I already tried adding the line below to `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/aliases.zsh` to change the `php` or `php.ini` path when I enter `wp --info`:

```
#MAMP Madness export 
PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH 
PHP_VERSION=`ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1` export 
PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH
```

I also tried changing the line below on the `wp-config.php` file, which didn't work:

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:8889');
```

Any help would be appreciated. I really would like to use WP-CLI locally on my Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, MAMP is not installed in a place that `wp-cli` expect it to be installed. And the MySQL socket file is needed to by the application.

Creating a symbolic link would help.

1. Locate the socket file location either in `tmp` or `var`

   ```
   netstat -a | grep mysql
   ```

   In the case of MAC Sierra and MAMP PRO, you have `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`
2. Create a symbolic link to this file

   ```
   cd /var 
   sudo mkdir mysql
   sudo chmod 755 mysql
   cd mysql
   sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock mysql.sock
   ```

If this did not work you can also add a symbolic to `tmp` folder.

```
cd tmp
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock mysql.sock
```

This is a tweak to the answer by @Brain Lowe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219970/warning-mysql-connect-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-connect-vi)

Comment: I just used Local from Flywheel (https://localwp.com/) instead where I can easily use the WP CLI.

Comment: My wp command complained about there being no /tmp/mysql.sock, and the second symbolic link in /tmp worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @risingPhoenix1979 I used localwp and it works really well so far. You can also use the addon for xdebug. That is sweet!

Comment: Can anyone confirm that the answer from @pensebien works on MAMP?

I've given up using MAMP with the WP-CLI and currently use Local (https://localwp.com/) as the WP-CLI works on my Mac out of the box with no configuration.

Comment: @risingPhoenix1979 I did that and it worked. LocalWP does not work well with MAMP if you have the both installed on your system.